# Como personalizar el orden de los resultados en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en donde guardo los post de un foro que hice con PHP y Mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `sala_muro_temas` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoria` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_clase` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_autor` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `autor` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titulo` text,
  `descripcion` text,
  `imagenes` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `borrado` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sala` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ejercicio` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
)
```

Ahora quiero agregarle la funcion para que se pueda fijar los post que el usuario elija arriba de todo y que se muestren primero. Para hacerlo he creado una tabla en donde guardo el id del usuario y el id del post fijado:

```
CREATE TABLE `sala_muro_temas_fijados` (
  `id_usuario` bigint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_tema` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Mi duda es como realizo la consulta SQL para que primero se muestren los post guardados por el usuario y luego el resto. Espero puedan guiarme. Gracias!!

Comment: Agrega estructura de las tablas para que te podamos dar una mano y sea mas facil armar la consulta

Comment: ok, ahora lo edito. Gracias

Comment: Listo Juan. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Patricio la relación entre ambas tablas, es la siguiente? id_usuario(muro_temas_fijados) -> id_autor(muro_temas) y id_tema(muro_temas_fijados) -> Id(muro_temas)

Comment: Si, asi es @Rostan

Answer (score 2):

Tomando como referencia la respuesta de rostan, vamos a cambiar unas cosas.

La primera consulta con los temas del usuario.

```
SELECT
     b.*
     2 campoOrdenamiento 
FROM muro_temas_fijados AS a
INNER JOIN muro_temas AS b ON (A.id_tema = B.Id)
WHERE A.id_usuario = @Tu_variable_usuario)
```

Despues realizar la union de las dos consultas

```
 UNION
```

Para los temas que no estan fijados, vamos a usar este codigo, para que tome en cuenta todos los post no fijados.

```
 SELECT
     b.*
     1  campoOrdenamiento
 FROM muro_temas AS B
 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID_TEMA FROM muro_temas_fijados WHERE A.id_usuario = @Tu_variable_usuario)
```

Por ultimo colocamos el ordenamiento

```
ORDER BY campoOrdenamiento, ID DESC
```

Esto para que te ordene por el ultimo id fijado y tambien este el orden los id no fijados. Espero este te funcione

Comment: Hola Martin, gracias por tu ayuda, no lo hago de esa manera porque varios usuarios pueden fijar un mismo tema... creo que no seria practico. Abrazo!

Comment: Hola Patricio, entendi mal tu pregunta, la mejor opcion es la que te propone rostan. Voy a tomar como referencia la pregunta de el, para realizar un cambio en su logica y funcionaria.

Answer (score 0):

Como necesitas primero obtener los temas del usuario y luego el resto, te recomendaría hacer una **UNION** de dos consultas, de la siguiente forma:

```
-- La primera consulta con los temas del usuario.
(SELECT* 
FROM muro_temas AS B
INNER JOIN muro_temas_fijados AS A
    ON (A.id_usuario = B.id_autor
        AND A.id_tema = B.Id)
WHERE A.id_usuario = @Tu_variable_usuario)

UNION -- Union de ambas consultas

-- Los temas que no son del usuario
(SELECT* 
FROM muro_temas AS B
INNER JOIN muro_temas_fijados AS A
    ON (A.id_usuario = B.id_autor
        AND A.id_tema = B.Id)
WHERE A.id_usuario <> @Tu_variable_usuario)
```

Espero mi respuesta sea de tu ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Rostan, tu repuesta esta correcta si el necesitara los post de otros usuarios, entiendo que lo que necesita son los post fijados de "Juan" y los post no fijados de "Juan". Pero puede que la pregunta no este muy entendible.

Comment: En la descripción de la pregunta el cita "...primero se muestren los post guardados por el usuario y luego el resto", con ello asumo que quiere priorizar los post del usuario buscado y luego el de los demás. De no ser ella la correcta definición dejemos que Patricio nos lo aclare en un comentario. Saludos.

Comment: Estimados, muchas gracias por sus respuestas, en el foro hay muchos usuarios y cada uno puede publicar, entonces por ej... el usuarios 1798 quiere fijar arriba de todo un post... por ej el post de Id 123, entonces lo que yo quiero es que el usuario 1798 vea primero el post 123 y despues todo el resto- Espero haberme podido explicar. Gracias!

Comment: Pero en ese sentido, el post 123, es el útimo post de él y lo desea ver primero, luego ver los demás incluyendo post viejos de él también?

Comment: Cuando te refieres al resto e solamente los de ese usuario o los de todos los usuarios.

Comment: Los post que se quieren fijar arriba pueden ser de cualquier usuario (no solamente sus propios post). Con el resto de los post me refiero a TODOS (los propios y los del resto). Gracias